# custom login form

Tags: forms, media, users

I want to create a custom login but I don't know where to start,

See the image for more details:

[image]

Is there anyway to create a custom HTML and add it the drupal login logic? maybe with a REST or API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very good tutorial on [Customising the login form](http://drupal.org/node/19855).

Answer (score 2):

I got what you need but please mention which Drupal version you are using; you can have a look at [this module](http://drupal.org/project/fancy_login) if you need: It is one of the best module for customizing the login of a Drupal system in the Drupal way.

Comment: @Xavi Colomer are you able to find the solution or you need some help there?